# How to insert multiple rows of data into Mysql DB with php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have this code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$page_name = 'Send Emails';
    require_once('header.php');
    if(!empty($_POST['send'])){
        $id_mail= "";
        foreach ($_POST['selected'] as $key => $value) {
            echo "$key - $value <br>";
            $id_mail .= "$value, ";
            }
            $id_mail= substr($id_mail, 0, -2);
        }
    if(!empty($_POST['Send2'])){
            $mail= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT mail FROM students WHERE student_id IN($_POST[id_mail])");
            echo "SELECT mail FROM students WHERE student_id IN($_POST[id_mail]) ";
            while ($row_mail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mail)) {
                echo "$row_mail[mail] ";
            $to = $row_mail['mail'];
            $subject = $_POST['head'];
            $message = $_POST['body'];
            $headers = 'From: code-week@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Please do not reply to this message' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }

        }
?>
<form name='mail2' method='post' action='send_email.php'><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="id_mail" value="<?php echo $id_mail; ?>">
    <br/>

<input type='text' name='head' placeholder='header'>
<br/>
<br/>

<textarea name='body' rows="4" cols="50" placeholder='body'></textarea><br/>
<br/>
<input class='btn btn-danger'type='submit' name="Send2" value='Send'>
</form>
```

It's purpose is to read the ID of a selected row from a table of students, print it so I can see it's selected correct from the previous page, then based on it, send an e-mail to all the people with a selected ID. My question is, how can I then write the sent email (just the subject and message part), combined with the selected students ID's in a new Mysql DB table? Every time I've tried to do it with a normal INSERT query, It says the selected ID is invalid, assumes it is 0, and writes the subject and message and in the ID column, it inputs the assumed value - 0. If I have 2 or 3 people selected (2-3 ID's ) it writes the first one and then I get an error. If the first field is full (ID is 0 for it), it outputs an error and writes nothing.
The end result should be a table with 3 columns - student id, email subject and e-mail message. The purpose is to notify selected students and then write the message in a table, so I can see witch students have been notified.

Comment: very lengthy to read...please ask in structured way if you want your question, answered...

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Nobody would read through all of that.

Comment: I am sorry, don't know how to explain in correctly without it being so long.

Comment: ...unless you're a speedreader ;-)

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($conn))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: I have a table of students signed up for a 1 week coding course. They sign up, and based on some internal assessment, valid candidates are chosen from a MySQL table with all entries, their status is changed, and based on their ID in the table, They are sent an email to notify them. I need the sent email to be kept in a new table with the student's id, to know who is notified, so they don't get another email.

Comment: @Fred-ii- My main problem is, that I select 3 people that need to get the same e-mail, but the email needs to be written in a new table on 3 different rows, with the first column being the ID of the student.

Comment: you say you're getting errors but didn't say what they were.

Comment: Here is an error message. This does manage to insert email data to the table, but the index number is wrong, so it works for one row, once.
Notice: Undefined index: mail_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpProject\send_email.php on line 32
 Error: INSERT INTO `sent_mails` (`id_student` , `mail_head` , `content`) VALUES ('', 'dbdb', 'cvdfvdvf')
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'sadd@fsd.bg <- this, 2 times because there are two selected people.

Answer (score 2):

First of all it's better not to use unescaped POST data in your queries, as it might lead to a [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

As for the 'insert' part - if you have all the necessary fields, primary keys and default values, just use an [INSERT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) statement to save the data

Answer (score 2):

1). Make a column for `is_notified` and originally set it's value to zero.

2). As soon as the email has been sent to a student, update the `is_notified` column to 1.

If you want to multi update, using PDO, you can use this :-

```
<?php
try
{
    $s = $conn->prepare("your SQL");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

foreach(loop through the ids here)
{
    $s->bindParam(':paramname', $paramvalue);
    $s->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: this looks like a good alternative, thanks. As always K.I.S :)

Comment: @MihailIvanchev Don't forget to accept the answer which helped you ;)

Comment: can you give an example of your code that is not PDO? like object or procedural? I don't use PDO in my work and it would be harder to implement it.

Comment: @MihailIvanchev I can, but I would recommend you to use PDO.

Comment: Sorry, this will not work. I thought it will do the trick, but the person I am making this for, basically wants this to have a similar functionality to a mail box. The idea is to save sent emails into a type of 'Sent E-mails' table in the DB, witch I can display. Just changing the status from 0 to 1 does not cut it.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Comment: This would work, yes, but I have no idea how many VALUE fields I would have. If I write it for 3 rows, and select 5 people to be sent an e-mail, it will not work. If I write it for 5 rows, but input data for just 3, again, not working. If the code after VALUE can somehow be dynamic, based on the selected people for emails, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if(!empty($_POST['Send2'])){ 
14             $mail= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT student_id, mail FROM students WHERE student_id IN($_POST[id_mail])"); 
15             echo "SELECT student_id, mail FROM students WHERE student_id IN($_POST[id_mail]) "; 
16             while ($row_mail = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mail)) { 
17                 echo "$row_mail[mail] "; 
18             $to = $row_mail['mail']; 
19             $subject = $_POST['head']; 
20             $message = $_POST['body']; 
21             $headers = 'From: code-week@example.com' . "\r\n" . 
22             'Please do not reply to this message' . "\r\n" . 
23             'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
24             mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
25             $sent_mails= mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO sent_mails (id_st, mail_head, content) VALUES ('$_POST[id_mail]', '$subject', '$message') "); 
26             if (mysqli_query($conn, $sent_mails)){ 
27              echo "Success"; 
28             } else { 
29              echo "Error ". $sent_mails . "<br/>" . mysqli_error($conn); 
30             } 
31             } 
32         }
```